# Sqlalchemy error when getting return type

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

While retrieving the column type of Array receiving the below error in SQLALCHEMY(HANA)
col_def["type"] = coltype()
TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item_type'

Comment: heres a snip from my code from sqlalchemy import inspect, MetaData, create_engine

engine = create_engine("hana_connection")
md = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
insp = inspect(engine)
columns_table = insp.get_columns(hana_table, hana_schema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using SQLALCHEMY I used HANA built in views to solve this problem